# How spring community manages version of the framework

Tags: spring, maven, jenkins, artifactory, maven-release-plugin

I want to know more about how Spring Community manages versions of the Spring Framework. (For example versions of spring-core and spring-mvc). To be more specific:

1. How do you change version in pom xml?

   a) You change it by yourself in pom.xml?
   b) Or you use maven-release-plugin?
   c) Or you use some tool in artifactory or jenkins - or other build tool?
2. How do you promote from SNAPSHOT version to RELEASE ?
3. How your team organized for version changes?
4. Do you open new branch for the new future?

This questions looks like simple one - but I more interested in learning best devops practices from spring team. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overlfow! Perhaps you should ask Spring directly ? With such question, you'll end up with people's opinion on how releases should be done. You should try to rephrase with a problem you currently have. [See questions to avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: The problem is - that they closed there forum and instead have page via stackoverflow api and even more - I don't have any specific technical problem - I make devops job right now - And I should make recommendation for about 300 hundred developers in one organization. So I want to hear out some thoughts about this problem even not from spring community members - I took them just as good framework (yes and i want to hear from them also) with many modules and versions.

Comment: So, here they say that I should direct all spring questions to stackoverflow  http://spring.io/blog/2014/06/18/retiring-the-forum-spring-io-website

Comment: OK I understand. Spring may very well answer your question, which is visible on their "monitored questions" page (https://spring.io/questions). And I'm rooting for your question to be answered, I was merely advising you how to improve your question and ensure it doesn't get closed!

Comment: This may be a good read for you: [spring-Gradle-build-and-release-FAQ](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Gradle-build-and-release-FAQ)

Comment: and this [Spring-project-versioning](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-build-gradle/wiki/Spring-project-versioning)  In fact, [this page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-build-gradle/wiki) has links to both pages and some more (the very first line suggests the up to date information is the first link in the previous comment).

Comment: Thank you for helping me. We don't use gradle - but maven.

Comment: Your question is about Spring process, so it shouldn't matter whether you use maven and they use Gradle.

Comment: Thanks, I think, you answered my question!